# The code is triggering 2 function at once | discord.py

Tags: python, sqlite, discord, discord.py

So I tried to make a filtering system, when the warning is less than 3, it works fine until it reaches 4 which means (the ban time) it triggers the mute tho. Here is the code

```
    @commands.Cog.listener()
    async def on_message(self, message):
        if not message.author.bot:
            if not message.author.guild_permissions.manage_messages:
                for b in ignored:
                    if b in message.content.lower():
                        return
                    else:
                        self.cur.execute(f"SELECT text FROM badwords WHERE guild_id = {message.guild.id}")
                        result = self.cur.fetchall()
                        bword = [x[0] for x in result]
                        if any(b in bword for b in message.content.lower().split(" ")):
                            self.cur.execute(f"SELECT onoff from mutedet WHERE guild_id = {message.guild.id}")
                            result3 = self.cur.fetchone()
                            if result3 is not None:
                                self.cur.execute(f"SELECT role FROM mute WHERE guild_id = {message.guild.id}")
                                mutedet = self.cur.fetchone()
                                if mutedet is not None:
                                    self.cur.execute(f"SELECT warn FROM warning WHERE guild_id = {message.guild.id} and user_id = {message.author.id}")
                                    result2 = self.cur.fetchone()
                                    if result2 is None:
                                        role = discord.utils.get(message.author.guild.roles, id=int(mutedet[0]))
                                        sql = f"INSERT INTO warning(guild_id, user_id, warn) VALUES(?,?,?)"
                                        val = (message.guild.id, message.author.id, 1)
                                        self.cur.execute(sql, val)
                                        self.db.commit()
                                        await message.channel.purge(limit=1)
                                        await message.author.send(f"Hey {message.author.mention} you are muted for 10 Minutes, keep doing this will result on getting banned.")
                                        await message.channel.send(f"Hey {message.author.mention}, That word isn't allowed here!")
                                        await message.author.add_roles(role)
                                        await asyncio.sleep(600)
                                        await message.author.remove_roles(role)
                                        await message.author.send("You are unmuted, If you keep doing this you'll be banned!")
                                    elif result2 is not None:
                                        self.cur.execute(f"SELECT warn FROM warning WHERE guild_id = {message.guild.id} and user_id = {message.author.id}")
                                        warnamount = self.cur.fetchone()
                                        role = discord.utils.get(message.author.guild.roles, id=int(mutedet[0]))
                                        wcount = int(warnamount[0])
                                        if wcount >= 3:
                                            self.cur.execute(f"DELETE FROM warning WHERE guild_id = {message.guild.id} and user_id = {message.author.id}")
                                            self.db.commit()
                                            await message.author.send("You have been banned, because of 3 Violates in a row!")
                                            await message.author.ban(reason="3 Violates in a row!")
                                        else:
                                            self.cur.execute(f"SELECT warn FROM warning WHERE guild_id = {message.guild.id} and user_id = {message.author.id}")
                                            warnings = self.cur.fetchone()
                                            warns = int(warnings[0])
                                            sql = f"UPDATE warning SET warn = ? WHERE guild_id = ? and user_id = ?"
                                            val = (warns + 1, message.guild.id, message.author.id)
                                            self.cur.execute(sql, val)
                                            self.db.commit()
                                            await message.channel.purge(limit=1)
                                            await message.author.send(f"Hey {message.author.mention} you are muted for 10 Minutes, keep doing this will result on getting banned.")
                                            await message.channel.send(f"Hey {message.author.mention}, That word isn't allowed here!")
                                            await message.author.add_roles(role)
                                            await asyncio.sleep(600)
                                            await message.author.remove_roles(role)
                                            await message.author.send("You are unmuted, If you keep doing this you'll be banned!")
```

[image: Picture of the DM from the bots]

After the message author got banned, somehow it adds into db as 1 again :/
Any suggestion of better codes logic please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That function is very large you should refract it to the smaller more abstract version.
Like I think you are testing message for containing bad words you can create a function for it which checks for bad words and return true or false.
You can wrap database operations in function which will be more meaningful and easier to write and reason about.

Separate your database logic from code wrap it into a function

The reason why you're getting muted message again is that you are deleting warning after it reaches 3 and when he sends message back as a warning for users has been deleted result2 is None again and this loop continues.

A possible solution can be to use a table which includes banned members once warning exceeds you can put the user into that table.